# Travis CI deploy to S3 bucket using the "glob" option uploads all repo files

Tags: amazon-s3, travis-ci

I'm using Travis CI's deploy feature to upload all png files that contain `screenshot-` to S3 using the following configuration:

```yaml
deploy:
  on:
    all_branches: true
  provider: s3
  access_key_id:
    secure: $ACCESS_KEY
  secret_access_key:
    secure: $SECRECT_ACCESS_KEY
  bucket: $BUCKET_NAME
  upload_dir: $DIRECTORY_PATH
  glob: "**/*/screenshot-*.png"
```

But it's uploading all the repo files to S3, not only the files with the pattern I provided.

*UPDATE: the `glob` option works with or without quotes for the value. That's not what's causing the issue. I tried both and both didn't work.*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`glob` works perfectly only on Travis dpl v2

[https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment-v2/providers/s3/#:~:text=secret_access_key%3E%0A%20%20bucket%3A%20%3Cbucket%3E-,edge%3A%20true,-%23%20opt%20in%20to](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment-v2/providers/s3/#:%7E:text=secret_access_key%3E%0A%20%20bucket%3A%20%3Cbucket%3E-,edge%3A%20true,-%23%20opt%20in%20to)